# Git clone for Windows working with Direct Access

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, vpn, ipv6

I have a laptop that has Direct Access enabled . I am using Windows 7 . The version of git client is

> D:\projects\directaccess>git --version git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0

The git server I am running is gitLab 7.0

When I am inside the corporate network everything works fine .
 When I am outside the corporate network

- I am able to access the git repository using http interface .
- But the git clone command does not work . It says host cannot be resolved .

My understanding based on this excellent article ( http://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2014/01/13/troubleshooting-name-resolution-issues-on-directaccess-clients ) is that the git client is not using the NRPT  ( Name Resolution Policy Table )

Some additional tips :

- ping works
- putty works
- nslookup DOES NOT work (unless i add a -server option pointing to the DNS64 address as mentioned in the article )

So question is :

- How to get git clone working ?

Comment: As a short term work around does your GIT host have a static IP? Can you use that instead?

Comment: Nope . The way DirectAccess is configured it works only for FQDN and not for IP Address . And I don't have a static IP Address opened for the external world that is accessible

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the support for IPv6 in the version of Git client I was using . i upgraded my git client to

> C:\Windows\system32>git --version git version 2.5.3.windows.1

and things worked smoothly